# Http Api Response : List Vs Map

Tags: json, web-services, rest, http

I have a `Price` object that contains an unique `Item Id`, `Mrp`, `Discount`, `Seller Price`.

There is an Http Api exposed that given a list of Item Ids returns their data. Now there are two ways of doing this.
For example: If someone does a GET on `A,B,C`, the response:

**Approach 1:** Return a List of Price Objects:

```
[
    { "ItemId" : "A",
      "Mrp" : 55.0,
      "Discount" : 0.0,
      "Seller Price" : 55.0
    },
    { "ItemId" : "B",
      "Mrp" : 100.0,
      "Discount" : 10.0,
      "Seller Price" : 90.0
    },
    { "ItemId" : "C",
      "Mrp" : 75.0,
      "Discount" : 0.0,
      "Seller Price" : 75.0
    }
]
```

**Approach 2:** Return a Map of Price Objects:

```
{
    "A" :{ "ItemId" : "A",
           "Mrp" : 55.0,
           "Discount" : 0.0,
           "Seller Price" : 55.0
         },
    "B" :{ "ItemId" : "B",
           "Mrp" : 100.0,
           "Discount" : 10.0,
           "Seller Price" : 90.0
         },
    "C" :{ "ItemId" : "C",
           "Mrp" : 75.0,
           "Discount" : 0.0,
           "Seller Price" : 75.0
         }
}
```

An advantage of Approach 2 over 1 is the flexibility it gives the client of iterating as well as a lookup, but with the tradeoff that extra data flows over the wire. Now i do not want to move out Item Id from inside the entity, cause the entity loses its meaning without it, plus clients would then have to plug in Item Id to complete the object and then pass it along to some other clients.

What is the best practice for this. Any other approach for doing this.

Since the Api is in designing phase, anything can be accommodated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do the second option unless there was a clear use case for the client almost always wanting to immediately consume a map and my data was already in the form of a map.

For an internal api it would make for a reasonable convention as long as you were visit consistent, and I don't think another developer would be surprised if they saw it.

It's really not very difficult to turn a list into a map.

Unless you are working in a very unusual environment, I wouldn't worry about the extra data being sent down the wire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, well, the item ids are 24bytes long, and we support batch reads of 30, so approx 24 * 30 bytes = 720 bytes extra per request. We serve at a QPS of 10000 qps on normal day(peaks around 60k), so that would make it on a normal day 10000 * 720 bytes extra per second, which would mean an unneccesary bandwidth utilization of 57.6Mbit/sec, which can be better used. But are there any best practices around this?